# Eevee: Background-texture is reflected, but light-emitting text-object is not - how to fix?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection, emission

Using Evee - How do I get my text with an emissive material to reflect in the bumped watersurface?

In this setup the background is an HDRI (the stonewall and the window):

[image]

The text is just text with an emissive material

[image]

The water is a plane where the illusion is created by bumping:

[image]

I'm sure the explanation is simple, but as I am just learning blender, I have no idea what to look for.

Comment: Did you check Screen Space Reflection in your render settings?

Comment: Nope - and that's the answer! Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Answer was suggested by MikoCG - thnx man!

I have to turn on "Screen Space Reflections" in the Render Properties!

[image]

Comment: Glad to help you and no worry, sometimes people forget about such trivial setting, even I do, also I have noticed that your water surface uses subsurface color but your subsurface value is 0, so that pink color is not going to be shown

Comment: That's just the way the principled BDSF works. Subsurface will always have a color, it's just the strength that determines if it is visible (and nope, I don't want my water to be pink :D )

Comment: I was talking about why there is pink color set, normally it is white, so I thought that maybe you want your water to be pink :D, and yes subsurface will always give you red by default due to subsurface radius being set for R = 1

Comment: I think I was testing the effect of subsurf at one point, and needed a bright and ugly color to make the effect clear :)